# WPF TextBox Bound to Model Class, Updates Textbox from Updated Property , but Typing into Box Does Not Update Property or Text Value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, textbox

Working on a WPF project I have gotten stuck trying to bind data between a Model class and Textbox. I have an ObservableObject class that is inheriting INotifyProperty Changed:

```
    public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        
    }
```

Then this class is inherited into my Data Model class UpdateUIDValues tracking 2 Properties:

```
public class UpdateUIDValues : ObservableObject
    {

        public UpdateUIDValues() { 
        
        }

        public UpdateUIDValues(string value)
        {
            this.UIDRef = value;
            this.LogRef = value;
        }


        private string _UIDRef;
        public string UIDRef {

            get {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_UIDRef))
                    return "Unknown";
                return _UIDRef;
            }
            set {
                _UIDRef = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("UIDRef");
            }
        }

        private string _LogRef;

        public string LogRef
        {

            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_LogRef))
                    return "Unknown";
                return _LogRef;
            }
            set
            {
                _LogRef = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LogRef");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Over in my ViewModel , I have a MainViewModel class that opens an instance of UpdateUIDValues so that it is an accessible property of the View Model my View uses :

```
class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public RelayCommand UIDViewCommand { get; set; }
        public UIDViewModel UIDVm { get; set; }
        public UpdateUIDValues UpdateUidValues { get; set; }

        private object _currentView;

        public object CurrentView
        { 
            get { return _currentView; }
            set
            {
                _currentView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel() 
        {
            UIDVm = new UIDViewModel();
            CurrentView = UIDVm;
            UpdateUidValues = new UpdateUIDValues();

            UIDViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o => 
            {
                CurrentView = UIDVm;
            });


        }

    }
```

My View Xaml then is setting its DataContext as the MainView:

```
     <Window.DataContext>
       <viewModel:MainViewModel>
       </viewModel:MainViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

With the TextBox in Question :

```
         <TextBox x:Name="logidBox"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  Style="{StaticResource UpdateBox}"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Text="{Binding UpdateUidValues.LogRef,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
        />
```

Finally, in my UpdateUID.xaml.cs :

```
    UpdateUID() {
    
        MainViewModel mainView = new MainViewModel();
    
        public UpdateUID()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = mainView;

        }
        
        private void updateUIDWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        
                mainView.UpdateUidValues.UIDRef = "SomeString";
                mainView.UpdateUidValues.LogRef = "SomeString2";
        }
    
    
    }
```

The property seems to be correctly accessible by my View Xaml, and when the Loaded event gets called it correctly seems to set either property and then change both text boxes to the updated property. For example, in this case, SomeString and SomeString2. So it appears the Property binding is working to update the Textbox. However, if I type into the TextBox after this the property is not updated, and after evaluating the TextBox.Text value stays locked to the Property value regardless of what is typed into the box. What am I doing wrong here that the TextBox is not either :

1. Updating the property value
2. Not updating the Text value of what is literally typed into the box? The goal here is that on load certain values are loaded into the text boxes, and from there, users can change the text value typing into it which should also change the property value.

Comment: What is `UpdateUID`...is that the same as what you call your MainView or is it another window/control?  Secondly, why are you setting the DataContext twice; once in the view xaml and again in UpdateUID.xaml.cs? Thirdly, remove the strings you are passing into every `OnPropertyChanged`, because you've declared `[CallerMemberName] string name = null` which will automatically resolve your property names for you (and it will avoid silly string typos, if any exist).

Comment: I removed the pass in strings for the OnPropertyChanged events. Thanks.

The UpdateUID is the code behind for the main view, UpdateUID.xaml . Idea here
is that window will load, a row of data will be broken up and send its strings
into the text boxes. 

If I don't set the this.DataContext the boxes never get the initial strings passed into
them from the bound data. Inside the UpdateUID I have an instance of my ViewModel
that is being used to create a new instance to set property values to from the code behind.

Comment: You don't need to set the DataContext twice. Ever. If you debug and put a breakpoint on the open brace of your `updateUIDWindow_Loaded`, then in the Watch window type 'DataContext', you'll see that it is already set to the `MainViewModel` instance that you declared in your UpdateUID.xaml.  To prove this, change your `mainView.UpdateUidValues.UIDRef = "SomeString";` to `((MainViewModel)DataContext).UpdateUidValues.UIDRef = "SomeString";` and it will still work.

Comment: I took your code and created a [minimum sample project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sYjQPeHS85jHNT1Vh3Q8iwNFSOtb4uvb/view?usp=sharing) for you to try, and I am not seeing the problem that you are stating. If I put a breakpoint on line 52 of the UpdateUIDValues.cs on the LogRef setter, it hits the breakpoint, which indicates that the Model is updating with literally what I type into the TextBox.